# Why is the <span attribute(text), retrieved in reverse sentences requests, python?

Tags: python, html, utf-8, request, arabic

I'm trying to get the text attribute from the span elements, each element contains a paragraph,
the retrieved paragraph is in reverse in terms of sentences,

example of one span element:(there are 5 span elements, I joined their text )

`<span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:14.0pt;font-family:&quot;Simplified Arabic&quot;; mso-ascii-font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;;mso-fareast-font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;; mso-hansi-font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;">حظيت حكومة السيد عبد الكريم الكباريتي التي تم تشكيلها في 4 شباط (فبراير) 1996 باهتمام أردني وإقليمي لم تحظَ به حكومة أردنية أخرى منذ سنوات طويلة، مما يعكس حجم التحديات التي تواجهها هذه الحكومة سواء على المستوى الداخلي أو الإقليمي.<o:p></o:p></span>`

the output result as viewed from a csv file:
`[' حظيت حكومة السيد عبد الكريم الكباريتي\r\nالتي تم تشكيلها في 4 شباط (فبراير) 1996 باهتمام أردني وإقليمي لم تحظَ به حكومة\r\nأردنية أخرى منذ سنوات طويلة، مما يعكس حجم التحديات التي تواجهها هذه الحكومة\r\nسواء على المستوى الداخلي أو الإقليمي.']`

my code:it insludes a loop for multiple span elements

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-8')
    abstract_el = soup.find('div', id='BodyContentPlaceHolder_divText')
    spans =abstract_el.find_all('span')
    subs=''
    for sub in spans:
        subs+= ' '+sub.text
    ar_abstract.append(subs)
```

the expected result:
`حظيت حكومة السيد عبد الكريم الكباريتيالتي تم تشكيلها في 4 شباط (فبراير) 1996 باهتمام أردني وإقليمي لم تحظَ به حكومة أردنية أخرى منذ سنوات طويلة، مما يعكس حجم التحديات التي تواجهها هذه الحكومة سواء على المستوى الداخلي أو الإقليمي.`

a continuous line that is logically written( Arabic reading is required to understand the problem with mispositioned sentences

Comment: use `dir="rtl"`

Comment: There are potentially problems with the markup. But before investigating that what are you displaying the results in? A jupyter notebook? In a terminal? Other?

Comment: @Andj I'm saving to csv and opening the file from vs code and excel

Comment: @mhj.DA I suspect you have multiple problems, the first being the the HTML you are scrapping, and I suspect additional areas at various points in your pipeline. If I look at your expected result, and i grab the source of the expected result, copy the inner html and paste it into an RTL environment, the first word is "حظيت" and the final word is "الإقليمي" does this match with your expectations? But without seeing the source, and the final results its difficult to unpick what is happening, pasting samples into stackoverflow muddies the waters.